Set up OpenIddict to accept both internal and external tokens
How to allows a service to both authenticate tokens it issues itself and authenticate tokens from another service on a different port?
I'm trying config like this but it not working, it only understands tokens that are issued at port 7226 it doesn't understand tokens that are issued by itself. How can it understand both?
services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddValidation(options =>
    {
        options.UseLocalServer();
        options.EnableAuthorizationEntryValidation();
        
        options.SetIssuer("https://localhost:7226/");
        options.AddEncryptionKey(new SymmetricSecurityKey(
            Convert.FromBase64String(Configuration["OpenIddict:EncryptionKey"] ?? string.Empty))
        );
        
        options.UseSystemNetHttp();
        options.UseAspNetCore();
    });


What happens when you call AddValidation twice, once with UseLocalServer and once with SetIssuer(...)?

I use with UseLocalServer for authorize internal service, but I want authorize from service different.  I'm tried remove SetIssuer in AddValidation and code AddJwtBearer
So it understand self-issuing token but not understand token by port 7226

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
options.DefaultScheme = OpenIddictConstants.Schemes.Bearer;
options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIddictConstants.Schemes.Bearer;
})
.AddJwtBearer(OpenIddictConstants.Schemes.Bearer, options =>
{
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
ValidateIssuer = true,
ValidIssuer = "https://localhost:7226/",
TokenDecryptionKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
Convert.FromBase64String(Configuration["OpenIddict:EncryptionKey"]))
};
});
